# GZip .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: gzipstream, .net-cf-3.5

I am trying to send and receive process gzip-ed data from server on my client device application (not web).
I am sending gzip-ed content and on client side, I have following method that returns WebResponse:

```
protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
{
    WebResponse res = base.GetWebResponse(request);

    if (((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)(res)).ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
    {
        Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    }

    //This returns g-ziped content as WebResponse, but I need to return 
//above decompressed responseStream as WebResponse, how do I do that?
    return res; 
}
```

I am new to this but I am thinking that intercepting every response comming to my app in GetWebResponse is excellent centralized spot to decompress all responses.  But the problem is how to pass the decompressed stream as response back?

Much appreciated